# Clone Linux OS disk safely (not dd or Clonezilla)

Tags: linux, backup, data-recovery, disk-image

I would like to clone my Linux OS drive, to a same/larger disk. And I will do this periodically.

On Windows I use AOEMI Partition Assistant to clone disks. The GUI is very good and idiot-proof. However, Linux isn't supported.

I have tried Clonezilla and I didn't find the walkthrough completely obvious/idiot-proof.

`dd` petrifies me in case I make a mistake.

Is there anything else to recommend? Particularly anything which contains explicit safety checks to ensure the current OS drive is not over-written.